# How to insert values through inner join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]
[image]

Could anybody tell me how to do insert statement with inner join.

i am trying to insert 
`ProductName,ProductCompany,ProductPrice,ProductQty` in `Product` table and `CategoryName` in `category` Table. And i also want to fetch `Category_id` to the `Category_id_FK`.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

1. First add Category information
2. Get ID number against that Category using function [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and save value to a variable
3. Then use product detials and that varible to insert values in Product table

.

```
DECLARE @CategoryName VARCHAR(200),
        @Category_id INT


SET @CategoryName='CategoryName1';        

INSERT INTO Category(CategoryName)
SELECT @CategoryName;


SELECT @Category_id= SCOPE_IDENTITY();    --- 


INSERT INTO Product(ProductName, Category_id_FK, ProductCompany, ProductPrice, ProductQty)
SELECT 'ProductName', @Category_id , 'ProductCompany', 'ProductPrice', 'ProductQty';
```

Comment: Your statements are missing statement terminators. From [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563%28v=sql.110%29.aspx): ***`;`** Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for **most statements** in this version of SQL Server, it will be **required in a future version**.*

Comment: (1) You better be sure `CategoryName` is unique, but (2) why not use the more reliable `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, which is in memory and doesn't require an additional table access?

Comment: Actually @AaronBertrand in past i have faced issues for using @@identity then big boss resolved it and replaced @@Idendity with SCOPE_IDENTITY() somehow I forget function so That was the only method i remember. thanks for reminding me.

Comment: The [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) clause would also give the identity value.